# How do you find $f(x)$ if its sine transform is $2πs^{½}$?

Tags: fourier-transform

We can define the Fourier sine transform as
$$F[f(x)](s)=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f(x) \sin (sx) dx\:.$$

Now the inverse sine transform is $$f(x) =\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}F(s) \sin (sx) ds\:.$$

I have used this formula to evaluate the value of $f(x)$ but I can't.

Comment: please use latex commands to produce a better layout for the question

Comment: Is this about [Mathematics.SE]?

Comment: What is your function? $F(s) = 2\pi\sqrt s$? Shouldn't it be an odd function (and defined everywhere)?

Comment: But indeed, better ask to have this question moved to mathematics.

Answer (score 1):

The problem that you ask has no answer because $\sqrt{s}$ is imaginary for  for negtaive  $s$. The answer that  I *think* you are after is problem 1) part (b) of [this](https://courses.physics.illinois.edu/phys508/fa2020/508hw4.pdf) homework set. I think that there is enough explained there for you to finish it off yourself.